# Foreign Key Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, chave-estrangeira

Tenho uma dúvida refente a foreign key na seguinte situação:

Tehno a tabela UF, com 3 colunas:

ID_UF (PK), Cod_UF (int) e DescUF (nvarchar(50))

Tenho outra tabela chamada IDE, com 3 colunas:

ID_IDE (PK), Cod_UF(int) e DescIDE (nvarchar(50))

Quando tento criar uma FK entre as duas tabelas com a coluna Cod_UF o Sql dá um erro de identificador único.

Eu entendo o motivo do erro, porem qual a melhor solução para criar uma FK em um situação desta?

**EDIT:**

Respondendo a dúvidas sobre Cod_UF:

A coluna ID_UF é o código interno da aplicação referente a determinada UF.
A coluna Cod_UF é o código que o IBGE determina.

A tabela IDE recebe informações de um documento preenchido por terceiros que recebo via webservice.

Como não tenho controle deste webservice nem tenho como validar as informações preenchidas pelo cidadão do outro lado do webservice pensei em criar esta FK entre a tabela UF e a tabela IDE para evitar de salvar nesta tabela um código do IBGE que não exista.

Comment: Não seria melhor você renomear `Cod_UF` de `UF` para `CodIBGE`?

Comment: Seria, inclusive até já mudei depois de postar a pergunta para Cod_IBGE, pois li os comentários e percebi que o nome da coluna poderia causar confusão no futuro.

Comment: Ok, mas da resposta, falta alguma coisa? Precisa que eu complemente algo mais?

Comment: Já pensei na solução da pergunta porém ainda não achei uma forma de evitar inserção de códigos do IBGE que não existam na tabela UF

Comment: Editei a resposta, com a dica de `UNIQUE` para sua coluna `CodIBGE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ..., qual a melhor solução para criar uma FK em um situação desta?

Apontando as chaves estrangeiras apenas para as chaves primárias. Por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE UF (
    ID_UF INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    Cod_UF INT NOT NULL,
    DescUF nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IDE (
    ID_IDE INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    Cod_UF INT NOT NULL
    DescIDE nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE IDE
ADD CONSTRAINT IDE_UF_FK FOREIGN KEY (Cod_UF) REFERENCES UF (ID_UF);
```

Aliás, não entendi por que tem duas `Cod_UF` nas duas tabelas.

---

**EDIT**

Para evitar que `CodIBGE` não possa admitir valores duplicados, use:

```
ALTER TABLE UF
ADD UNIQUE (CodIBGE);
```

Ou:

```
ALTER TABLE UF
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_UF_CodIBGE UNIQUE (CodIBGE);
```

Comment: Acho que a relação entre UF e IDE é de 1->N, por isso ele precisa do cod_uf como FK na tabela IDE. Pelo menos foi o que eu entendi.

Comment: Sim, mas ainda assim é estranho. Se justificaria se fosse um campo `Sigla`, ou se tem código interno e externo. Mas código interno e externo é uma prática meio problemática.

Comment: É, verdade analisando melhor ficou estranho mesmo, pois o PK de UF é ID_UF.

Comment: Fiz um edit na pergunta explicando o por que de ter Cod_UF em duas tabelas.